# I keep getting "invalid column name" when i execute my code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 Create Database FinalDatabase
 GO

 USE FinalDatabase
 GO

 /*
 Create tables
 */

 Create TABLE tblSalesPerson
 (
     SalesID INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
     FName VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
     LName VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
 )
 GO

 Create TABLE tblCustomer
 (
     CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
     Name VARCHAR(24)NOT NULL,
     Address VARCHAR(48)NOT NULL,
     City VARCHAR (48) NOT NULL,
     State VARCHAR (2)NOT NULL,
     ZIP VARCHAR (5)NOT NULL,
     Phone VARCHAR (10)NOT NULL,
 )
 GO

 Create TABLE tblItem 
 (
     ItemID INT IDENTITY (1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
     Description VARCHAR(100),
     UnitPrice MONEY
 )
 GO

 Create TABLE tblInvoice
 (
      InvoiceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      Date DATE NOT NULL,
      Subtotal MONEY ,
      SalesTax MONEY ,
      Total MONEY ,
      ShipDate DATE,
      ShipHand MONEY NULL
 )
 GO

 Create TABLE tblLineItem
 (
      LineItemID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      Quantity   INT NOT NULL,
      Amount MONEY,
      UnitPrice MONEY,
 )
 GO

 --Echo a print statement that confirms result.
 PRINT 'Tables successfully constructed...'

 SET NOCOUNT OFF

 ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
 ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_ID_FK 
     FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES tblCustomer(CustomerID)
 GO

 PRINT 'Foreign Key Constraints successfully applied...'

 -- Alters tblInvoice to require CustomerID 
 ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
 ALTER COLUMN CustomerID INT NOT NULL
 GO

 --Cannot give away orders....must have a total
 PRINT 'NOT NULL Constraints successfully applied...'

 ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
 ALTER COLUMN Total MONEY NOT NULL
 GO

 PRINT 'NOT NULL Constraints successfully applied...'

 --If you have any default constraints
 PRINT 'DEFAULT Constraints successfully applied...'

 ALTER TABLE tblCustomer
 ADD CONSTRAINT Name_Phone_Unique 
     UNIQUE(Name, Phone) -- makes this an alternate key
 GO

 PRINT 'UNQUE Constraints successfully applied...'

--Check to make sure Ship Date is in the future
 ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
 ADD CONSTRAINT ShipDate_Future_Check
     CHECK (ShipDate > Date)
 GO

   PRINT 'CHECK Constraints successfully applied...'


  SET NOCOUNT ON

  GO

  --Insert Customers

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  --INSERT INTO tblCustomer 

  INSERT INTO tblCustomer (Name,Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone)
  VALUES ('Larry Bond', '1225 Meddle St', 'Williamsburg', 'MS', '39457', '2286562989')

  COMMIT TRANSACTION

  PRINT 'Customers successfully inserted...'

 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
 DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(500)
 SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Rolledback transaction: Customer  insertions.'
 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16,1)
 END CATCH
 GO



  --SELECT * FROM tblCustomer





    --Insert Invoice And SaleItem

    BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @CustomerID INT
    SET @CustomerID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM tblCustomer WHERE Name = 'Jeffrey Donald' AND Phone = '2285882673')

     DECLARE @SalesID INT
     SET @SalesID = (SELECT SalesID FROM tblSalesPerson WHERE FName = 'Randy')


     INSERT INTO tblInvoice (DATE, CustomerID, SalesID, Total, Salestax, ShipDate, ShipHand)
     VALUES ('2010-8-5 8:30 am', @CustomerID, @SalesID, '174.44', '17.44', '2010-8-6 8:45 am', '10.99')


    --Retrieve the newly created primary key to insert as a foreign key in tblLineItem
     DECLARE @InvoiceID INT
     DECLARE @ItemID INT

     SET @InvoiceID = @@Identity

    --Retrieve primary key of product for current listitem
    --Insert new row in tblSaleItem
    SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Red Jaguars Shirts XL')

    INSERT INTO tblLineItem ( Quantity, Amount, UnitPrice, InvoiceID, ItemID)
    VALUES (2, 52.66, 105.20, @InvoiceID, @ItemID)

    SET @ItemID = (SELECT ItemID FROM tblItem WHERE Description ='Red Jaguars Hoodies XL')

     INSERT INTO tblItem (ItemID, Description, UnitPrice)
    VALUES (@ItemID, 'White Jaguar Sweatpants', '124.56')
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(500)
     SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' Rolledback transaction:    insertions.'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, 16,1)
    END CATCH
   --New Invoice






   SELECT * FROM  tblCustomer
   SELECT * FROM tblInvoice
   SELECT * FROM tblItem
   SELECT * FROM tblLineItem
   SELECT * FROM tblSalesPerson 

   SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

These are the errors that I am receiving I have more code if you need to look at more.

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 88
>   Foreign key 'Customer_ID_FK' references invalid column 'CustomerID' in referencing table 'tblInvoice'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 88
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
>
> Msg 4924, Level 16, State 1, Line 96
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN failed because column 'CustomerID' does not exist in table 'tblInvoice'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 187
>   Invalid column name 'CustomerID'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 187
>   Invalid column name 'SalesID'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 201
>   Invalid column name 'InvoiceID'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 201
>   Invalid column name 'ItemID'.

Comment: Do you have `CustomerID` and `SalesID` column in `tblInvoice` table

Comment: No I tried adding them as foreign key constraints

Comment: post your table schema:  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblInvoice`

Comment: Adding the  foreign key constraint does **NOT** add a column! That column **must be present** before you can define it as a foreign key constraint! Also: why are you defining a column like `Total MONEY` in `tblInvoice` and then later on changing it to `NOT NULL`?? Why not just define it as `Total MONEY NOT NULL` right from the beginning??

Answer (score 1):

The first error is due to this

```
Create TABLE tblInvoice
(
InvoiceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Subtotal MONEY ,
SalesTax MONEY ,
Total    MONEY ,
ShipDate DATE,
ShipHand MONEY NULL
)
GO
```

And this

```
ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
ADD CONSTRAINT Customer_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
REFERENCES tblCustomer(CustomerID)
GO
```

There is no CustomerID column in tblInvoice.
If you want to add a column, do this **before** you add the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE tblInvoice
ADD CustomerID INT NOT NULL
GO
```

Similarly, you do not have the SalesID in the invoice table and you are trying to insert data to it.

```
 INSERT INTO tblInvoice (DATE, CustomerID, SalesID, Total, Salestax, ShipDate, ShipHand)
 VALUES ('2010-8-5 8:30 am', @CustomerID, @SalesID, '174.44', '17.44', '2010-8-6 8:45 am', '10.99')
```

Comment: So I suppose to add them in each table it need it in? Do I  set it as foreign key?

Comment: Yes. You have to have the column in the table first. After that, you create the foreign key.

Comment: Mostly from I observed, you did not have the column in the table, and you are trying to work with these "ghost" column.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it question though do I add the identity(1,1 ) with them to the tables they are entered in?

Comment: Why do you want an identity(1,1)? If you get the value of that column from another table, then NO, you do not want an identity(1,1). If it is from an original table, where you will insert data in and let it automatically created for you, then YES.

Comment: Thanks it worked I got this other error saying Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 219
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CustomerID', table 'FinalDatabase.dbo.tblInvoice'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. Rolledback transaction:  insertions.

Comment: Because it was the NOT NULL constraint (I copied it from your original code). You can drop the column and recreate it as NULL. (Use the same statement, just get rid of the NOT NULL part)